# How can I make permanent changes to a list using a function in python tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to enter an item into the entry box press a button and add the item to the list changing the list permanently, however I cannot seem to make a permanent change to the list. The program always returns "[]" and never the updated list. Is there a way I can do this?

I have tested and there are no issues involving extracting text from the entry box and adding It to the list. The only problem is making the change permanent.

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

names = []

ent = Entry(window)
ent.pack()

def change():
    names.append(ent.get())

btn = Button (window, command = change )
btn.pack()

print(names)

window.mainloop()
```

why is the response always "[]" and not the updated list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [try to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) **understand** the problem before posting. "why is the response always "[]" and not the updated list" - well, think carefully about the logic of the code. When will `print(names)` happen? (Hint: will the code stop running after `btn.pack()`? Why?) When will `names.append(ent.get())` happen? (Hint: what is the purpose of the button?) Therefore, which happens first - putting the name into the list, or displaying it? So, is the result surprising?

Comment: "I have tested and there are no issues involving extracting text from the entry box and adding It to the list." **How did your test work**? "The only problem is making the change permanent." **Why do you believe** the change is not "permanent"? However you tested the contents of the list, did you try doing that **after** clicking the button? Does it not work if you click the button a few times?

Comment: For more general hints, please also read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

It is printing an empty list because the list is empty. You are not printing after appending

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

names = []

ent = Entry(window) ent.pack()

def change():
    names.append(ent.get())
    print(names)

btn = Button (window, command = change ) btn.pack()

#print(names)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @tmabraham i answered only to the printing issue that you asked in your question. As you work more on your code you will find more bugs. Research more into each issue and if you can't find the solution, you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

While mapperx's answer is correct, I think what you're trying to do is to persist the list, so that when you close the program and open it again, the names are still there. If this is what you intend, you need to store the list (or its content) into a file before closing the program. 
 You can do this using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle

window = Tk()

# Create list from file (if no file exists, create empty list)
try:
    with open('names.pickle', 'rb') as f: names = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError: names = []

ent = Entry(window)
ent.pack()

def change():
    names.append(ent.get())

btn = Button (window, command = change )
btn.pack()

print(names)

window.mainloop()
# This will run after the window is closed (unless exception is thrown!)
with open('names.pickle', 'wb') as f: pickle.dump(names, f)  # Store (persist) the list
```

You can change `names.pickle` to any filename you want

Comment: Bare `except`s are bad practise. Also if there is an error/the process stops for some reason, `onClose` will not be called.

Comment: @TheLizzard corrected the bare except with "FIleNotFoundError" also changed the onClose, it will still fail to save if the process stops but I don't see that as a problem